# Duplicate in part? Solved

Tags: discussion, support, moderator, questions, exact-duplicates

I had a question that had a part of it that included the duplicate, but it mostly was not a duplicate. Can it be reversed if it was mistaken? I was not voted on hold but moderator put it on hold. I have removed that part since non of the answers reflected it.
[Why are centrifuges not used on the space station? revised](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26470/why-are-centrifuges-not-used-on-the-space-station-revised)

Comment: Despite the title focusing on sleeping, the questions are actually the same--they both want to know why centrifuges are not used for astronauts. Is there something missing in the answers to that question? If so, please edit your question further to clarify.

Comment: @called2voyage   If the title reflected the subject I would have saved the trouble. Can the title be changed to better cover the subjects? This is a design flaw in searching for prior questions.

Comment: Agree, I'll update the title

Comment: @called2voyage Thank you for  helping me and letting me participate!